# Bootstrap Split button dropdowns not showing but not dropping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, it's working fine except the dropdowns I have the css and js files properly and the btn group shows fine but when I click on it it doesn't do anything. where is my problem? thanks

```
       <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Action</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Are you clicking on 'Action' or the caret? Your code seems to work fine on Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/63724

Comment: If you want to have 'Action' activate the dropdown, change it to `<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown">Action</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure our what the problem was, it had nothing to do with bootstrap the problem was with piece of script I wrote somewhere for submitting form, it seemed to me it has nothing to do with my code but I was wrong.